# split one number into multiple numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

Here's the example:

We have **total hours** worked by an employee. The amount of hours is 10.

The normal limit is 8 hours. What's beyond this amount is called *overtime*.

**Normal Hours** = 8 and **Overtime** = 2. So we split number 10 into 8 & 2.

Here's my implementation, please pardon my `C#`:

```
/*
 *  NormalLimit equals 8; value is the number of hours set for the day
 */

if (value > _config.NormalLimit)
{
    dailyStatements[index].Normal = _config.NormalLimit;
    dailyStatements[index].Overtime = value - _config.NormalLimit;
}
else
{
    dailyStatements[index].Normal = value;
}
```

*Note that if we want to split a number into more than 2 numbers - we'll end up having multiple intricate IF blocks and the code is going to look obscure.*

Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: Depends, your solution is quite valid, although I also would like to see your `get`. Nevertheless consider this, you are talking about overtime, is something like `under-time` a valid thing? If so, you possibly can skip the `else`, take it in consideration and do it in 1 calculation.

Comment: @Stefan I am thinking of having a collection where limits are kept, than handling it somehow via a FOR loop. Trying to strain my brains at the moment.

Comment: @Stefan also, ignore get - let's imagine it's not a `set` statement but rather a method `void AddHours(decimal hrs)`

Comment: The reason I asked about the `get` is because this whole thing lives in your business logic context. You asked about a more elegant way, and besides the nicely given answer, there probably is, because you seem to violate some property's best practices, which can simply be undone when using a `void` method ;-)

Comment: Explain `Note that if we want to split a number into more than 2 numbers`. How many splits are going to be there for overtime?

Comment: @vivek_23 Say, we have a rule: *first 8 hours* billed at normal rate, *next 2 hours* are billed at 150% that rate, *next 5 hours* are billed at double (200%) rate. Those numbers 8, 2, 5 are boundaries sort of. And we produce **multiple amounts of hours** an employee has worked according to this rule.
But this is just an example. We may just be playing with numbers without any business context - the number of splits is generally more than 2 - that's what I imply.

Comment: @Stefan please pardon me, I'm just playing with C# fiddle locally, haven't wrote the business logic in `get`. Only using that code excerpt as an example.

Comment: @AlexHerman Let's say an employee has worked for 20 hours. Then, he has exceeded the 8 hrs slab along with 2 hrs and 5 hrs slab. In that case, what would be the scenario?

Comment: @AlexHerman: ah, then please ignore my comment :-)

Comment: @vivek_23 Good point. First, let's introduce working limit just to avoid torturing staff :) 15 hours is the ultimate limit. But also let's look at this splitting algorithm regardless of this particular business context. No employees, we just split numbers in accordance with a collection of boundaries. Where the limit of hours is the sum of all boundaries in the collection (in our case it's 8+2+5 = 15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, we can make an array of working hour slabs and another array for the rate of payment for each hour in those hours. Note that you can also make a class for this for more tight binding between working hours and payment rates.

```
class Solution {
    static void Main() {
        int[] working_hours = new int[]{8,2,15};
        int[] payment_rate = {100,150,200};
        int payment_per_hour = 500;

        for(int i=1;i<=15;++i){
            System.Console.WriteLine("Payment for " + i + " hour(s) worked: $"+ totalPayment(i,working_hours,payment_rate,payment_per_hour));
        }
    }

    private static int totalPayment(int hours_worked,int []working_hours,int []payment_rate,int payment_per_hour){
        int amount = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<working_hours.Length;++i){
            int curr_slab = Math.Min(hours_worked,working_hours[i]);
            amount += curr_slab * (payment_per_hour * payment_rate[i] / 100);
            hours_worked -= curr_slab;            
            if(hours_worked == 0) break;
        }

        return amount;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Payment for 1 hour(s) worked: $500
Payment for 2 hour(s) worked: $1000
Payment for 3 hour(s) worked: $1500
Payment for 4 hour(s) worked: $2000
Payment for 5 hour(s) worked: $2500
Payment for 6 hour(s) worked: $3000
Payment for 7 hour(s) worked: $3500
Payment for 8 hour(s) worked: $4000
Payment for 9 hour(s) worked: $4750
Payment for 10 hour(s) worked: $5500
Payment for 11 hour(s) worked: $6500
Payment for 12 hour(s) worked: $7500
Payment for 13 hour(s) worked: $8500
Payment for 14 hour(s) worked: $9500
Payment for 15 hour(s) worked: $10500
```

We take the number of hours worked by a candidate and then keep subtracting it from our working slabs, while also adding the amount to be paid respecting the work hour rate for a particular working slab.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the if/else by using `Math.Min` methods to choose the lower of a pair of numbers, and `Math.Max` to choose the higher.

```
set 
{
    // The actual value or the configured limit, whichever is lower.
    dailyStatements[index].Normal = Math.Min(value, _config.NormalLimit); 
    // The hours over the limit, or 0 if it comes out negative);
    dailyStatements[index].Overtime = Math.Max(value - _config.NormalLimit, 0) 
}
```

Comment: wow! that looks extremely simple and concise, great solution, will give it a try now.

Comment: Also, I imagine there'll be a collection of limits based on which we produce new numbers. `for` loop might be required. Thinking...